# Determine whether the graph of the function is the graph of a one-to-one function.

Tags: calculus, functions

the graphs in #44, 48, 63, 65, 68 For each graph, does it represent a one-to-one function?

[image]

my solution are:

## 44_ Yes ___

## 48____No____

## 63____Yes___

## 65____NO___

## 68___Yes____

I know that the function is one to one when there is unique value for every X so in the given graph we can see that every X has different value

but I'm not sure if my answers are correct or wrong .

please assist me to know how to determine if the graph represent 1-1 function or no

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

44 yes;48 No;63 Yes

65 No; 68 NO

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: I think 48 is one-o-one

Comment: 48 is  even not a function.